# What does a return type of <S extends CharSequence> S mean?

Tags: java, generics, scjp

```
public <S extends CharSequence> S foo(S s){
    return null;
}
```

I found this method in one of the OCJP question. But I find it difficult to understand what exactly the return type `<S extends CharSequence> S` means. Could someone having knowledge in Java explain me what it means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition `<S extends CharSequence>` means that `S` is a type that extends or implements `CharSequence`.

Note the presence of `S` before `foo` and after it. This means that `foo` returns a type that either extends or implements `CharSequence`, and accepts an argument of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

I means that method foo takes a CharSequence (or it's subclass or implementing class) and as a parameter and returns the *same* type as return value.

For example you can call the method like this

```
CharSequence s = ...
CharSequence result = foo(s);
```

or

```
String s = ...
String result = foo(s);
```

or

```
StringBuffer s = ...
StringBuffer result = foo(s);
```

However, it does not allow you to use mismatching return and parameter types. These are not ok:

```
String s = ...
StringBuffer result = foo(s);
```

or

```
StringBuffer s = ...
String result = foo(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

`S foo(S s)` means that the `foo` method takes a parameter of type  `S`, and will return an `S`.

Also the method `foo` is defining which type you can use it for: `S` (your templated result) is a subclass of `CharSequence`.

For example, you can call it using:

```
foo("example")
```

And that will return a String (It's valid because `String` is a subclass of `CharSequence`.

And this specific implementation returns null in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

The line reads:
Method `foo` takes as a parameter any object of type `S` and returns an object of type S, given `S` extends `CharSequence`.
If you take StringBuilder (extends CharSequence) for example and put it in this context it will give the following:

```
public StringBuilder foo (StringBuilder s)
```

Answer (score 0):

`<S extends CharSequence>`  is not a part the return type. It introduces a type parameter in your generic method `foo`. Here `S` is introduced as a type parameter (upper) bounded by `CharSequence`. `foo` takes a parameter of type `S` also returns the same.